# Incorrect documentation for ICU's BreakIterator?

Tags: c++, icu

I've come a cropper using the ICU break iterator. In [the example](http://userguide.icu-project.org/boundaryanalysis), they suggest using the following code to iterate through all boundaries:

```
void listWordBoundaries(const UnicodeString& s) {
    UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    BreakIterator* bi = BreakIterator::createWordInstance(Locale::getUS(), status);


    bi->setText(s);
    int32_t p = bi->first();
    while (p != BreakIterator::DONE) {
        printf("Boundary at position %d\n", p);
        p = bi->next();
    }
    delete bi;
}
```

This appears to indicate that `next()` actually mutates the iterator. However, the [documentation](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classBreakIterator.html#a68f3b6be789195b55204a6d86d58a8ad) seems to indicate that it's only effect is to return a value. Is this just an example of bad documentation? In particular, if `next()` is indeed mutating, I'd like to know if `last()` is also mutating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `current()` is const while `next()` and `last()` are not.   Yes, `next()` advances the iterator and `last()` sets it to the end position.  I've filed http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/ticket/9360 to fix the docs, thanks.

Comment: .. which ticket has been fixed.